# How to dynamically change the skin of an activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I change the theme of an Android app in an automated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the theme dynamically at runtime, call setTheme() in your activity's onCreate() method, before calling setContentView().  To change the theme, you simply need to restart your activity.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) on how dynamically apply themes.

and [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) one too.

Comment: thanks, these links are useful for me. 

is there a way that themes after download add to res/values/ by user?